# Is there a way to reinitialize jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, dom

### Question

JQuery is initialized on `import`. If `window` and `window.document` exist (and `module` doesn't), JQuery saves the references and uses them thereafter.

Is there a way I can "reinitialize" or "reset" JQuery after it's been `import`ed to give it a different reference to `window` and `document`?

### A failing testcase part 1

#### Project Structure

```
.
├── .eslintrc.json
├── .prettierrc
├── index.spec.js
├── package.json
├── README.md
├── spec/
│   └── support/
│       ├── jasmine-spec.json
│       ├── logger.js
│       ├── slow-spec-reporter.js
│       └── type-check.js
├── template1.html
└── template2.html
```

#### ./index.spec.js

```
import { JSDOM } from 'jsdom';

describe('jquery', () => {
  it('uses the currently available document', async () => {
    const { document: template1Document, jquery: template1Jquery } = await parseHtml('template1.html');
    expect(template1Document.querySelector('p').textContent).toEqual('Hello world');
    expect(template1Jquery.find('p').text()).toEqual('Hello world');

    const { document: template2Document, jquery: template2Jquery } = await parseHtml('template2.html');
    expect(template2Document.querySelector('p').textContent).toEqual('Goodbye world');
    expect(template2Jquery.find('p').text()).toEqual('Goodbye world'); // !!! 
    // Expected 'Hello world' to equal 'Goodbye world'.
  });
});

async function parseHtml(fileName) {
  const dom = await JSDOM.fromFile(fileName, {
    url: 'http://localhost',
    runScripts: 'dangerously',
    resources: 'usable',
    pretendToBeVisual: true,
  });
  const window = dom.window;
  const document = window.document;

  globalThis.window = window;
  globalThis.document = document;

  const dynamicImport = await import('jquery');

  const $ = dynamicImport.default;

  return {
    document: document,
    jquery: $(`html`),
  };
}
```

#### ./template1.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>template1.html</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Hello world</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### ./template2.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>template2.html</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Goodbye world</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is an excerpt of the code, but you can find [a complete github repository](https://github.com/DanKaplanSES/jsdom-sandbox/tree/reinit-jquery-so) here.

It's not enough to reinitialize one or some of the `import`ed jquery's, all the jquery references need to be reinitialized. For example, if a production file starts with `import jQuery from 'jquery'`, that `jQuery` needs to be a reference to the reinitialized jquery. This is hard to explain so I'll show what I mean with another failing testcase:

### A failing testcase part 2

#### Project Structure

```
.
├── .eslintrc.json
├── .prettierrc
├── index.spec.js
├── package.json
├── prod-code.js
├── README.md
├── spec/
│   └── support/
│       ├── jasmine-spec.json
│       ├── logger.js
│       ├── slow-spec-reporter.js
│       └── type-check.js
├── template1.html
├── template2.html
└── test-setup.js
```

#### ./index.spec.js

```
import * as testSetup from './test-setup.js';
import * as prodCode from './prod-code.js';

describe('jquery', () => {
  it('dynamic imports affect static imports template1', async () => {
    await testSetup.parseHtmlWithDynamicImport('template1.html');

    const { document: template1Document, jquery: template1Jquery } =
      await prodCode.parseHtmlWithJQueryStaticImport('template1.html'); // !!!
    // Error: jQuery requires a window with a document
    expect(template1Document.querySelector('p').textContent).toEqual(
      'Hello world'
    );
    expect(template1Jquery.find('p').text()).toEqual('Hello world');
  });

  it('dynamic imports affect static imports template2', async () => {
    await testSetup.parseHtmlWithDynamicImport('template2.html');

    const { document: template2Document, jquery: template2Jquery } =
      await prodCode.parseHtmlWithJQueryStaticImport('template2.html'); // !!!
    // Error: jQuery requires a window with a document
    expect(template2Document.querySelector('p').textContent).toEqual(
      'Goodbye world'
    );
    expect(template2Jquery.find('p').text()).toEqual('Goodbye world');
  });
});
```

#### ./test-setup.js

```
import { JSDOM} from 'jsdom'

export async function parseHtmlWithDynamicImport(fileName) {
    const dom = await JSDOM.fromFile(fileName, {
      url: 'http://localhost',
      runScripts: 'dangerously',
      resources: 'usable',
      pretendToBeVisual: true,
    });

    const dynamicImport = await import('jquery');
    const $ = dynamicImport.default(dom.window);
    return {
      document: dom.window.document,
      jquery: $(`html`),
    };
  }
```

#### ./prod-code.js

```
import { JSDOM } from 'jsdom';
import jQuery from 'jquery';

export async function parseHtmlWithJQueryStaticImport(fileName) {
  const dom = await JSDOM.fromFile(fileName, {
    url: 'http://localhost',
    runScripts: 'dangerously',
    resources: 'usable',
    pretendToBeVisual: true,
  });


  return {
    document: dom.window.document,
    jquery: jQuery(`html`),
  };
}
```

#### ./template1.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>template1.html</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Hello world</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### ./template2.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>template2.html</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Goodbye world</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is an excerpt of the code, but [you can find a complete github repository](https://github.com/DanKaplanSES/jsdom-sandbox/tree/reinit-jquery-dynamic-and-static-imports-failing-testcase-so) here.

### Context

I'm working on a frontend-only, single page app project. Even though the project runs exclusively in the browser, the automated tests run in Node.JS. The tests load the html in [JSDOM](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/) and execute portions of the production code.<sup>1</sup>

On creation, JSDOM returns a DOM API that works in Node.JS, including a `window` object. Without this, jQuery will error on **import** because modern versions [have code like this](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js):

```js
(function(global, factory) {

    "use strict";
  
    if (typeof module === "object" && typeof module.exports === "object") {
  
      // For CommonJS and CommonJS-like environments where a proper `window`
      // is present, execute the factory and get jQuery.
      // For environments that do not have a `window` with a `document`
      // (such as Node.js), expose a factory as module.exports.
      // This accentuates the need for the creation of a real `window`.
      // e.g. var jQuery = require("jquery")(window);
      // See ticket trac-14549 for more info.
      module.exports = global.document ?
        factory(global, true) :
        function(w) {
          if (!w.document) {
            throw new Error("jQuery requires a window with a document");
          }
          return factory(w);
        };
    } else {
      factory(global);
    }
  
    // Pass this if window is not defined yet
  })(typeof window !== "undefined" ? window : this, function(window, noGlobal) {
    console.log(`window`, window);
    console.log(`noGlobal`, noGlobal);
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

As you can see, this executes as a side effect of **import**ing jQuery. This has caused considerable headache because it isn't always straightforward to create JSDOM before importing jQuery.

For example, if the production code imports jQuery and the test imports the production code, JSDOM (and therefore `window`) won't exist yet. ~~This throws an error.~~ And when it's later used, `window` won't be set.

But here's a more important use case: I want to be able to use different HTML files in my tests, but this is limiting me to one per test run.

Someday, I'd like to release this test code as a test framework to the public. Some people may explicitly `import jQuery from 'jquery'` or `import $ from 'jquery'` or use a `jQuery`/`$` in the global scope. Ideally, they wouldn't have to modify their production code to use my framework.

---

### Notes

For the record, I'm using jQuery 3.7.1, but stackoverflow code snippets don't give me the option to pick that version. I think that's fine because, as far as I can tell, this code is the same in both.

<sup>1</sup>: Unfortunately, that means going against the official JSDOM advice. But in *this* context, I can't see a way around that.

Comment: Does what you're trying to do with automated testing require NodeJS and JSDOM other than that being a way you figured out how to do it, or would it be possible to shift this to running tests on itself in the browser instead?

Comment: @l3l_aze I think it might be *possible*, but it'd probably take less effort to modify jquery.js's source code to add my desired functionality. My project is written in typescript, for example. I don't want to compile it before running these tests (for performance reasons).

Comment: What exactly is the objective here? You want to be able to use jQuery in the context of the document?

Comment: I'm curious, what's the JSDOM advice you are referring to?

Comment: Also, is the jQuery really there just to run tests on the document content? I don't see any good reason to require it at all, as you pointed out yourself in the test code, you can use vanillaJS to achieve the same results.

Comment: @Salketer `I'm curious, what's the JSDOM advice you are referring to?` Search for "We strongly advise against trying to" [here](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/).

Comment: Do the html files include jQuery (using `<script src=...>`)?

Comment: @SalmanA good question: They do not. I could change them to, but I think that would make things even more challenging to reason about: the production code will still `import` `jquery`.

Comment: @daniel jQuery included in html could be referenced through window just like any global variable, import won't be needed. The actual challenge is that jsdom (apparently) returns the document before jQuery is loaded.

Comment: @SalmanA `jQuery included in html could be referenced through window just like any global variable, import won't be needed.` True, but I consider that a net negative to my production code: jQuery `import`s would become global variables.

Comment: @Daniel if you have not found the answer yet, could you please update the question with the specific issue you're facing?

Comment: @SalmanA See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77602661/is-there-a-way-to-reinitialize-jquery#comment136858171_77619075 for the specific issue I'm facing. It's not enough to reinitialize some jquery imports, I need to reinitialize all, ideally without modifying the production code.

Comment: @SalmanA I also updated the question by adding a second failing testcase.

Comment: Still not clear about the objective. So you have index.js and index2.js. Both have html parsing function. If I understand correctly, you need to attach jQuery to the document returned by the function (i) is that correct (ii) do you _also_ use jQuery _outside_ the parse html function in index2?

Comment: See revised answer.

Comment: @SalmanA I have updated the second failing test repository along with that section in my question. Hopefully that clarifies my objective, but let me know if not, and I'll do my best to improve it.

Comment: @SalmanA Also, I don't remember I put this in the original question (it's there now), but I think it's really important context that may have been missed: Someday, I'd like to release this test code as a test framework to the public. Some people may explicitly `import jQuery from 'jquery'` or `import $ from 'jquery'` or use a `jQuery`/`$` in the global scope. Ideally, they wouldn't have to modify their production code to use my framework.

Comment: @Salketer I have replied in the chat. You may also want to read my latest comments in this thread. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Everything is in your code already:

```
  // For CommonJS and CommonJS-like environments where a proper `window`
  // is present, execute the factory and get jQuery.
  // For environments that do not have a `window` with a `document`
  // (such as Node.js), expose a factory as module.exports.
  // This accentuates the need for the creation of a real `window`.
  // e.g. var jQuery = require("jquery")(window);
  // See ticket trac-14549 for more info.
```

This means that if there is no `window` with a `document` available on the global scope, the import will provide the factory it uses instead of executing it with the available window object and returning the instantiated jQuery.

If you change your parseHTML code to leverage this:

```
async function parseHtml(fileName) {
  const dom = await JSDOM.fromFile(fileName, {
    url: 'http://localhost',
    runScripts: 'dangerously',
    resources: 'usable',
    pretendToBeVisual: true,
  });
  //const window = dom.window;
  //const document = window.document;

  //globalThis.window = window;
  //globalThis.document = document;

  const dynamicImport = await import('jquery');

  //const $ = dynamicImport.default;
  const $ = dynamicImport.default(dom.window);
  return {
    document: document,
    jquery: $(`html`),
  };
}
```

If you do not make the window object available in the global scope, you'll receive the jQuery factory. You'll then be able to instantiate it the way you need, by passing the window object that you care about.

**More details on why your solution was not working**

When you import code/modules, the parsing and execution of the imported file is only done once (on the first import) and the resulting value is kept inside a cache so later imports do not need to work as much, but this causes your import value to always be the same.

Comment: I had to change this in the return `document: dom.window.document,`.

Comment: That jQuery code really confuses me. How is it that `dynamicImport.default(dom.window);` returns something completely compatible with the original line of `const $ = dynamicImport.default;`? Compatible in the sense that, at runtime, both are interchangeable. Also, am I indirectly calling one of [the documented `jQuery` functions](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) when I pass `dom.window` in?

Comment: Well, this is not only this line, it is also the fact that you remove the globalThis.document and globalThis.window. When there is no window available the jQuery object cannot be built, so the module returns a function that takes a window object and build the jQuery.

Comment: Ah, right. If there's no global `window.document` and there is `module.exports`, it returns a function that *requires* a `window` to be passed in, otherwise it'll throw an error: `throw new Error("jQuery requires a window with a document");` If that error message had only been a little more clear, I may not have needed to ask this question and I'd be 500 points richer ;)

Comment: Haha yes, those entrypoint codes are always hard to read/understand...

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to try this, but I found an issue: any file that statically imports `jquery` later (i.e., `import jQuery from 'jquery'`) will have a reference to the factory function, not the `dynamicImport.default(dom.window)` from your example above. That means that all the production code that `import`s jquery will have to be modified to use this solution. I thought of some modifications that would fix this:

Comment: 1) add a `jQuery(dom.window)` to every file with an `import jQuery from 'jquery'`. I think this will run in my tests but error in the browser: as the jQuery comment says, `jQuery` won't be a factory function in a browser environment. This seems like a bad solution for other reasons. 2) I can assign `dynamicImport.default(dom.window)` to `globalThis.$/jQuery` (I'm okay with this) and remove all the `import jQuery from 'jquery'`s from the production code—if possible, I'd like to avoid modifying the production code though. Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: So, from what I understand, you are running both production and test codes on the same project. Then yes the behaviour you are seeing is normal, the last paragraph of my answer explains why. You'd need two versions of jQuery, one for tests and one for production. I would keep the npm package for production and use a local copy for tests. The test imports would be like import jQuery from './testUtils/jQuery.js'. Note that the path is just a example.

Comment: `You'd need two versions of jQuery, one for tests and one for production.` But when running tests, how do I reinitialize *both*? I don't actually need or want two versions, I want one version that both use and that can be reinitialized in test code. Thinking off the top of my head, I might need to create my own wrapper file that imports jquery, initializes a factory method. Then modify all prod jquery `import`s to import the wrapper. Is there any way I can pull this off without modifying those prod `import jQuery from 'jquery';` lines?

Comment: In the end, I decided to go with [2) from my comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77602661/is-there-a-way-to-reinitialize-jquery#comment136858209_77619075). Since this worked, and the bounty was running out of time, and I couldn't of gotten this far without your answer, I wanted to award it to you. But in the hopes that a solution might exist where `import jQuery from 'jquery';` can stay in production code, I'm not ready to mark this question as answered.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I'd be happy to continue helping too but there's definitely something that I don't understand, could we do a 1:1 chat to try and reach a good conclusion?

Comment: @DanielKaplan I've created a room for discussion, https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256253/stackoverflow-com-questions-77602661

Comment: Thank you. I've left some messages. I'm not sure if I'll get notified if you reply so ping me here if I don't notice. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Read the note again:

```js
// For environments that do not have a `window` with a `document`
// (such as Node.js), expose a factory as module.exports.
// This accentuates the need for the creation of a real `window`.
// e.g. var jQuery = require("jquery")(window);
```

Inside your html parsing function, you get reference to ***jQuery factory*** which you can use to create a ***jQuery Object***.

That being said, you can use something along the following lines to initialize jQuery in both scenario described in OP:

```
  let jQuery_;
  if (typeof jQuery !== 'undefined') {
    // jQuery already imported statically using
    // import jQuery from 'jquery'
    jQuery_ = jQuery(dom.window);
  } else {
    // use dynamic import as described in
    // the comment inside jQuery code
    const dynamicImport = await import('jquery');
    jQuery_ = dynamicImport.default(dom.window);
  }
  // either way, we use jQuery factory to create jQuery
  // object bound to the document inside dom.window

  // PS: jQuery is different from jQuery('html')
  // you can do jQuery.ajax() and jQuery.browser
  // but you can't do jQuery("html").ajax() or jQuery.browser
  return {
    document: dom.window.document,
    jquery: jQuery_('html'),
  };
```

Comment: Am I required to use `require`? Can you convert this code to ESM?

Comment: See revised answer.